# custom vim syntax highlighting for angularjs is flaky

Tags: angularjs, vim, syntax, highlighting

I am doing angularjs development and have a bevy of HTML ng-templates included inside  tags in my HTML, like so:

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="content_listing.html">
              <div class="item_content">
               <div class="horiz-nav-menu">
                    <h3> {{sectionName}} </h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li ng-repeat="navLink in navLinks"> <a href='#/{{navLink.Target}}' title='{{navLink.Tip}}'>{{navLink.Text}}</a> </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
  </script>
```

It's highly annoying that my editor of choice, Vim, does not properly highlight the HTML because it is inside a script tag.  As a result, I have created a custom syntax region for Vim and plopped it into a file after/syntax/html.vim which I have confirmed is getting processed when Vim starts up:

```
unlet b:current_syntax
syn include @HTML $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim
syn region htmlTemplate start=+<script [^>]*type *=[^>]*text/ng-template[^>]*>+ keepend end=+</script>+me=s-1 contains=@HTML,htmlScriptTag,@htmlPreproc
```

The problem is that the highlighting behavior is flaky (Vim 7.2).  To make the highlighting work properly, I have to do things like scroll down so that the  section with HTML scrolls off of the page and then scroll back, hit :e to reload the doc, etc.  Also, even when the highlighting is displaying correctly, when I go to edit the HTML inside the  tag the highlighting for that block turns off.

I am no expert on Vim syntax highlighting ... has anyone run into a similar thing?  It looks to me like my region definition looks fine...

Comment: Putting any html tag inside a `<script>` tag is an aberration. Highlighting it as proper HTML would validate that aberration.

Comment: Generally that's true, however Angularjs explicitly encourages and supports this as part of its ng-template directive. What I am looking to do is provide highlighting that I would ideally make angular-specific once I get it working.

Comment: @romainl Modern web frameworks like AngularJS use the fact that the browser doesn't display the HTML inside `<script>` tags (and won't execute it, neither, if it's not marked as `text/JavaScript`), but that it can be accessed through the DOM. I see it more as a (overly?) clever way to put HTML snippets into the page without having to resort to ugly JavaScript string concatenation.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I do frontend dev so yeah, I know all that and that's gross and a very good reason to avoid angularjs: building your frontend on a hack...

Comment: In production these templates would not be in script tags, but instead be fetched via Ajax from the server side. During prototyping I like to do all the look-and-feel without a server, which is what putting the template in a script tag does -- it defines the template locally so that angular doesn't need to make a call to get it.

Comment: I pasted your snippet at the bottom of an HTML file, copied and pasted your three commands, and it worked fine.  I added a list element (typing in Insert mode), then deleted the new line (dd).  Try disabling other cruft or upgrading vim:  I am using 7.3.315.